# having trouble with cd and getting back to a directory

Tags: bash, directory, cd

For school, I have to switch between my top level directory which is git-basics-lab-online-web-sp-000 back to the sub directory I made which is called my-repository.
I was switching back and forth no problem using {cd} but when I tried to switch back to my-repository using

```
cd my-repository
```

my terminal is now saying

```
bash: cd: my-repository: No such file or directory
```

what did I do wrong?! How come it worked before but now it's giving me this message?

Comment: What is your current directory? Try `pwd` to see it. Do you see `my-repository` when you enter `ls`?

Comment: When I tried pwd it says im in /home/carefree-tutorial-7578. I do not see my-repository when I type ls either just git-basics-lab-online-web-sp-000. I made sure I created that directory and initialized it as well

Comment: you can use https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-command-unixlinux/ to have a better idea of how the directory tree looks like

Comment: @AraceliRamos : Use `cd -` to go back to the most recent directory. Consider using `pushd` instead of `cd`. In this case `popd` will not only bring you back to the most recent directory, but also maintains a directory stack, so you can hop back your chain of directories which have been set with `pushd`. Try it out, maybe you will like it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we are missing more information. That is, if you moved correctly from one directory to another, there is no reason why it should disappear just like that.

Besides `cd`, there are other commands that will help you to know which directory you are in, and where you can go. I summarize them below:

Show the full path to the current directory:

```sh
pwd
```

List files and folders (except hidden ones):

```sh
ls
```

Enter the `dir` directory (assuming it exists where we are):

```sh
cd dir
```

Exit `dir` (see edit):

```sh
cd ..
```

Obviously each command has a number of options that increase its functionality. You can always access them with the `man` command (for example, `man cd` will show you the `cd` command help).

That is, once the terminal showed you the error you mention, you can run `ls` to verify, for example, if you typed the folder name wrong. Then you can also try `pwd` to confirm that you are where you think you are. And finally you can move with `cd` to where you think you are.

**EDIT:** As suggested by Roadowl, `cd -` and `cd ..` are not strictly the same thing (in the example I assume we go one directory at a time).
I will try to illustrate this with an example to show the difference.

Suppose we have the `dirc` folder inside `dirb` and this, in turn, inside `dira` ( `dira/dirb/dirc` ). Let us also suppose that we are in `dira`. To enter directly to `dirc` we would have to execute `cd dirb/dirc`. And this is where the difference is illustrated:

- If we run `cd ..` we are going to be positioned in `dirb`.
- If we run `cd -` we will go back to the `dira` directory we were in before running the command.

Comment: `cd ..` is not exactly identical to 'go back'. `cd -` can be thought of as 'go back'.

Comment: Not really, I assumed I was advancing one directory at a time. You are right...

Answer (score 0):

This error message simply means that the directory/file you specified could not be found at your current location.  If you look to the left of where you are typing, your current directory should be displayed, something like `/you/are/here/ >`

You can type `cd ..` to navigate up one level (towards the root directory).

If you are sure the directory exists you are trying to cd into, then you probably just aren't currently in the right location, and you need to either `cd ..` or `cd somewhereelse` until you get there.

Comment: I'd associate `..` with "up" rather than "down".